# WPF application in Kiosk mode

Tags: c#, wpf, surface, kiosk

I have a WPF application that uses a TabControl to display lets say Tab1, Tab2 and Tab3.

1) How can I enable this application to run in Kiosk mode on Surface tablet as well as Windows touch PC devices?
2) My second question : Is it possible to disable Tab1 and Tab2 in Kiosk mode? The user will have access to only Tab3 in Kiosk mode.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows 10 Kiosk mode is for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps only. WPF apps don’t qualify.

[Microsoft provides instructions for configuring Windows for kiosk usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions), but most options require Windows 10 Enterprise or Education editions.

Comment: According to this link, the WPF application comes under classic Windows application, and can be installed for Kiosk mode. Is there any way to show specific tabs for Kiosk mode, such as Tab3?

Comment: The kiosk mode that link refers to for classic apps isn’t the standard Windows 10 kiosk mode (aka Assigned Access mode). Assuming you mean the shell launcher option, you could adapt the PowerShell code on that page to detect if it’s enabled (see `SLGetWindowsInformationDWORD()` from `Slc.dll`).

Comment: Thanks, Any idea how to work with features limitations in the Kiosk mode?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, you cannot use a WPF for Kiosk mode and need Windows Educational or Enterprise for Shell Launcher. A poor's man alternative is explained here: http://carlfranklin.net/blog/2015/6/13/kiosk-mode-in-windows-8x.html

Then put your exe file in the Startup folder as explained here: https://www.howtogeek.com/228467/how-to-make-a-program-run-at-startup-on-any-computer/