# Focus on my form window until input is taken C#

Tags: c#

I have a windows form myform which has a textbox and a button. I wonder how I can make the computer focus on myform where no other opened apps on the computer can be switched to until a text is entered in the textbox and the button is pressed then the user can access the rest of opened apps on the computer?

I tried this but it's not working as the computer kinda freezes:

```
bool focus = true;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = textBox1.Text;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\users\log.log", username);
    focus = false;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (focus)
    {
        this.textBox1.Select();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your while loop is blocking the UI thread. This is why your application will freeze until it exits the loop.

Comment: @RobinB I know, but how I can keep my form focused so that the user cannot access anything else until he enters the username and click the button?

Comment: In other words you are trying to replace the windows login process. Not an easy task

Comment: @Steve Yes, kind of, since I have many users +200 and only one user account on the computer and the number of users fluctuates up and down.

Comment: I suggest to put this as topmost, and then cancel close and minimize event

Comment: @Emanuele I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: You could start your program when the user logs in (instead of starting explorer). After successfull login, you can start explorer.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a ["Kiosk-mode application"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app)

Comment: You can set the Window to TopMost. You can also handle the 'Leave' event or 'LostFocus' but this way you will still not be able to prevent users to open the task manager and just kill your process.
I would check if there is something ready-to-use available. Have you checked on GitHub?

Comment: How would you prevent users from alt-tabbing to other apps when your app is showing its login window ?

Comment: TopMost https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.topmost?view=netframework-4.8
FormClosed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed?view=netframework-4.8
Deactivate: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Mihaeru Could you explain how this can be done so I can try it please?

Comment: Just check the answer from Darshan Patel. TopMost is shown there and much, much more. Most shortcuts are captured there as well, so that task switching is quite difficult. Not sure of you can also prevent Ctrl+Alt+Esc. The 'Leave' event you can easily handle but I'm not sure if or how you can switch back to your form if e.g. the task manager is called after Ctrl+Alt+Esc.

Comment: @Mihaeru - do not need to prevent Ctrl+Alt+Esc as taskbar is already in hidden state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF application in Kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262630/wpf-application-in-kiosk-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to achieve many case to do not allow user to use any other application except your application Like disable Taskbar, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> shortcut combination, Windows key, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> shortcut combination etc.

Here is similar code sample which can help you to get your desire output.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool IsClosingByButtonClick = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;

            #region Code for Disable ALT+TAB , WINDOWS, CTRL+ESC
            ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
            objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(captureKey);
            ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);
            #endregion

            Taskbar.Hide();
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                var cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;  // Turn on WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW
                return cp;
            }
        }

        #region Disable ALT+TAB , WINDOWS, CTRL+ESC
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public Keys key;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public IntPtr extra;
        }
        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int id, LowLevelKeyboardProc callback, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hook);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hook, int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);
        private IntPtr ptrHook;
        private LowLevelKeyboardProc objKeyboardProcess;

        private IntPtr captureKey(int nCode, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT objKeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lp, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));

                // Disabling Windows keys 

                if (objKeyInfo.key == Keys.RWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.LWin || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Tab && HasAltModifier(objKeyInfo.flags) || objKeyInfo.key == Keys.Escape && (ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1; // if 0 is returned then All the above keys will be enabled
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(ptrHook, nCode, wp, lp);
        }

        bool HasAltModifier(int flags)
        {
            return (flags & 0x20) == 0x20;
        }
        #endregion

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsClosingByButtonClick = true;
            this.Close();
            Taskbar.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsClosingByButtonClick)
                e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    #region TaskBar Integration to disable it.
    public class Taskbar
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int FindWindow(string className, string windowText);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(int hwnd, int command);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentHandle, int childAfter, string className, int windowTitle);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetDesktopWindow();

        private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
        private const int SW_SHOW = 1;

        protected static int Handle
        {
            get
            {
                return FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");
            }
        }

        protected static int HandleOfStartButton
        {
            get
            {
                int handleOfDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
                int handleOfStartButton = FindWindowEx(handleOfDesktop, 0, "button", 0);
                return handleOfStartButton;
            }
        }

        private Taskbar()
        {
            // hide ctor
        }

        public static void Show()
        {
            ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOW);
            ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_SHOW);
        }

        public static void Hide()
        {
            ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE);
            ShowWindow(HandleOfStartButton, SW_HIDE);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Also `Alt-F4` and `Alt-Space` which would terminate the application.

Comment: @ja72 Yes you are correct this needs to be implement. You can simply implement by prevent windows closing if button is not pressed. See my updated answer.

Comment: @DarshanPatel What about if someone pressed the windows key? I mean wouldn't it be easier to disable all the special keys (ctrl, alt, shift,....)?

Comment: @Tak windows key is already disabled. Please see my answer where related comment already mentioned.

Comment: @DarshanFaldu How can I include Ctrl+alt+del as well?